# In ViewGroup subclass component, how to tell when a referenced ViewPager has been initialized?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewgroup

I am building an activity that has a [`ViewPager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) in it and I am implementing a custom page indicator component that will show what page the view pager is currently showing. My question is: **How can my indicator component know when the view pager has been fully initialized?**

This component subclasses from [`FrameLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) and I have as a `declare-styleable` attribute a "pager" reference for this component. The intention is for the user to, in the layout XML, give my component the reference to the `ViewPager` component.

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Indicator">
        <attr name="pager" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

In the `onCreate` method of the activity, I assign the pager adapter to the `ViewPager` component:

```
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) { ...
```

My indicator component has to create subviews depending on the contents from the pager adapter set into the `ViewPager` component, so I have to create the indicator subviews after the adapter has been set.

What callback should I be using to ensure that the above `setAdapter` call has made, but before the activity has been displayed on-screen, to set up my subviews?

Answer (score 0):

I recently found myself in a similar situation.

Use the ViewPager’s post method with your own runnable. This basically queues your code after the view's measure. I think this could act as a proper “callback”.

```
viewPager.post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    //indicator stuff
   }
});
```